# Azure FileShare unreachable

Tags: azure

I'm trying to create a fileshare with Azure, but the connection test fails. My 445 is opened and the ping fails too.

Here the result

```
ComputerName           : formxxxxome.file.core.windows.net
RemoteAddress          : 40.xx.xx.28
RemotePort             : 445
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet0
SourceAddress          : 172.16.136.251
PingSucceeded          : False
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

I tried to ping the address from a web service like ping.eu but it fails too.

I set up the storage account to be accessible from All networks, and I tried to disable the secured transfert but it does not fix the problem.

EDIT: I'm using the free-plan, perhaps it's the reason of this failure? I noted that on several zones I can't create VM because nothing is available, perhaps it is the case with this storage account?

What do I miss?

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Ping is disabled for Azure resources so it will not respond to that.